# Expo integration with Google Sign In

Tags: react-native, expo, google-signin

I am trying to add login via Google account to my application. I have encountered a problem. Expo offers two solutions.

1. Google (https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/google/) - This can only be used in a development environment. I have used it but it does not work in a standalone application, in my case it throws the error "redirect_uri_mismatch" /
2. GoogleSignIn (https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/google-sign-in/) - Doesn't work in the emulator so I can't add it to the application because I can't fix potential errors.

My question is what the hell library should I use?

I have already tried `expo eject` and use Google Sign In from React Native. However I got an error that Expo does not support custom native modules. Help!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit: SDK 44 Release**

With the release of SDK 44, `expo-google-sign-in` has now been deprecated in favour of `expo-auth-session` OR `@react-native-google-signin/google-signin` packages. If you want to use the latter, you will need to follow the custom development client path.

**Pre SDK 44**

We've implemented Google-Sign-In using the `expo-google-sign-in` library. Implementation is easy enough, but you will have to test using a standalone build of your application which is the only slightly annoying piece of the puzzle.

Building a standalone build is now even easier with EAS (not sure if you have an account - but if you don't, I would highly recommend it.)

Comment: So I will have to build app to apk. file everytime when I will need to test it?

Comment: Only when you need to test social sign in specifically.

Answer (score 0):

I've used a `GoogleSignIn` library, but I also have pro tip for everyone who will implement it.

Instead of building a project every time when you will need to test it, you can build it once and then just use upadate OTA, it's much faster.